# SQLALchemy access column objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to find my way around SQLAlchemy. And i'm trying to find out how i can access the Column objects through a table instance.

I currently have my application written with Peewee as ORM and there i can do the following:

```
In [15]:from db.models.vehicle import Vehicle
In [16]: Vehicle.code
Out[16]: <db.fields.RsCharField at 0x7fd93e53e780>
In [17]: Vehicle.code.default
Out[17]: ''
```

or through an actual instance:

```
In [10]: a = Vehicle()
In [11]: a._meta.fields["code"]
Out[11]: <db.fields.RsCharField at 0x7f08ce49da90>
```

When i do the same in SQLAlchemy , i get an:

```
In [11]: Vehicle.code
Out[11]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7fd9105f2938>
```

But i want to have the actual Column type, since i extended the Column type to have extra attributes i want to access:

```
class RsColumn(Column):

    def __init__(self, *args, ui_group=None, ui_sequence=None, **kwargs):
        self.ui_group = ui_group
        self.ui_sequence = ui_sequence
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

(So in this case i want to access the RsColumn objects, that i use in my Table declaration)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Vehicle.__table__.c.code.type
```

You can read about it in [SQLAlchemy Documentation: Accessing Tables and Columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns)

Comment: If the answer helped you, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the Sergey's Answer,
accessing the relationship attributes in a table class returns the InstrumentedAttribute.

For accessing the columns of the child tables from parent table.

for example,

```
class Bbc(Base):
    name = Column(String)
    ...
    code_policy = relationship('CodePolicy') # related via foreign key
```

```
class CodePolicy(Base):
    policy_description = Column(String)
```

If you want to access the columns in the CodePolicy table from Bbc table via the code_policy relationship, then

```
Bbc.code_policy.property.table.c.policy_description
```